# Patch for Firefox

Tags: firefox

I have been recommended to install a patch to fix Firefox bugs concerned bookmarks (i.e. right mouse click not working & delays in showing bookmarks in a folder). I do not understand how to install the patch.However, I am not able to get an answer on Launchpad (bug 1195380).

The webpage showing the patch is at:
http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~mozillateam/firefox/firefox-trunk.head/view/head:/debian/patches/unity-menubar.patch

Help please!

Comment: In there [they say](https://bugs.launchpad.net/globalmenu-extension/+bug/1195380/comments/7) the patch is applied to the package already. So I suggest just wait until it is released into repos. If You don't want to wait You can add [Mozilla Daily](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-daily/+archive/ppa) ppa.

Comment: According to Launchpad, the fix is committed. It's taking a while for the package(s) to be released to repos. How can I find out when the package(s) will be released to repos?

Comment: I guess the best way to find out -- is to ask at the launchpad thread. Have You tried Mozilla Daily?

Comment: Re "add Mozilla Daily ppa". I am unwilling to do this as I will have Firefox updated every day and it may lead to more bugs in Firefox due to the ppa's package instability. I have asked (on the Launchpad thread for bug 748850 when the firefox package(s) will be released to Ubuntu's repositories.

Comment: You can add ppa, install firefox from there, and remove ppa -- while still retaining its firefox.

Comment: I will do as you suggest if I don't get any reply from Launchpad within a day or two.

Comment: No reply from Launchpad. I asked one of Ubuntu's testers and his response is that Mozilla will release fixed version of Firefox but they do not inform Canonical as to when that will be. IMO Canonical should pressurise Mozilla for the release date, given that the bugs so significantly affect the user experience.  Just had a good laugh when I saw (in the Register) about 'Continuous Development' i.e. to liaise properly between Devs & Deployers so that user expectations are satisfied.

Comment: Continuation:  Anyway, I'll give it another week before trying Mozilla Daily ppa (especially seeing as they  have faled to build a week ago & have not tried again: issue there is finding out which bugs are fixed & if there are any regression bugs - given that 'my' bugs are regression ones!

Comment: I have installed firefox-trunk package (version 26.0 built 5 days ago) from ubuntu-mozilla-daily ppa on Launchpad. However, restarting Firefox still leads to Firefox 23.0 being loaded (according to Help>About). How do install Firefox 26.0 from the package? Also, how do I find out which bugs have been fixed by Firefox 26.0?

Comment: I executed firefox-trunk from the Dash & it loaded Firefox 26.0. However, it still has same irritating bug (748850): right mouse  click on entry does not give option to open new tab etc & right mouse click on folder does not give options such as sorting entries in folder.

Answer (score 1):

Bug 748850 in Firefox has a workaround:
You have to use the terminal or a file explorer.
See http://kb.mozillazine.org/index.php?title=UserChrome.css
In my case is in ~/.mozilla/firefox/randomalphanumeric.default/
You have to create the directory "chrome" and inside it the file "userChrome.css" with this text:

```
#bookmarks-menu-button{
display:-moz-box!important;}
```

Then restart FF.